# Disable all modules except Mage/Core modules that are needed

Tags: admin, database, third-party-module, system-configuration

I've used this script before to enable all.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data`
  SET `value` = '0'
  WHERE `path` LIKE 'advanced/modules_disable_output/%';
```

Is there an easy way to disable all except MAGE/CORE modules?

Answer (score 0):

To truly disable all extensions (prevent execution) change the active value from true to false in all the non Mage xml files in /app/etc/modules/*

An easy way to do is would be open all the relevant xml files in your editor and complete a find and replace in open files

Comment: Alternatively and instead of having to edit all the files you can also create a folder called "disabled" and move all the 3rd party modules XML files to this folder